# wordpress multisite htaccess redirect site to TWO subsites

Tags: htaccess, redirects

EDITED:
I've split a website into two subsites in a multisite enviroment.

The old site was moved to a subsite, and renamed o`ld.mysite.example`.
This will be faced out at some point.

During development I had a redirect sending all visitors to the `old.mysite.example` subsite. Now that the work is done I need a very spesific redirect.

I want users that type in `old.mysite.example` sent back to `www.mysite.example`
Where as I want users clicking on postlinks such as `old.mysite.example/an-article-here` sent to `new.mysite.example/an-article-here`.

Now redirect that removed the first mentioned redirect is working. But not the other. Anyone got a good way to do this ?

Comment: Isn't this just a _standard_ domain redirect? Although you've created a new subdomain for the new site, rather than using the same hostname as the original site??

Comment: Actually it is a more complex thing than that. It didn't solve the entire issue. But I don't know how to re-open the question. I split the old website into a multisite-solution. So What I actually need is a redirect that will send users who type old.mysite.com to the www.mysite.com where as those who click on postlinks such as old.mysite.com/an-article-here is sent to new.mysite.com/an-article-here.

Comment: @XanderMan Please edit the question to include the _.htaccess_ code that you've tried or having partially working. Thanks.

Comment: So you desire to have any deep link go to a new site and the home page go to a different new site?

Answer (score 1):

NB: Any redirects that you add to `.htaccess` need to go *before* the WordPress front-controller.

> I want users that type in `old.mysite.example` sent back to `www.mysite.example`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.mysite\.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.mysite.example/ [R=302,L]
```

The regex `^$` matches an empty URL-path, ie. a request for the document root only.

> Where as I want users clicking on postlinks such as `old.mysite.example/an-article-here` sent to `new.mysite.example/an-article-here`

This is assuming you have already updated all the internal links on your own site and this is just for the benefit of any external 3rd parties (or search engines) that have linked to `old.mysite.example/an-article-here`.

Following the above redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.mysite\.example [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) https://new.mysite.example/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The regex `.+` ensures it matches *something* and not *nothing*, so as not to conflict with requests for the document root that redirect elsewhere. Although with the directives in this order, it shouldn't really matter.

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) only once you have confirmed the redirects are working OK. This is to avoid erroneous redirects being cached by the browser.

Clear your browser cache before testing.